# Rsync freezing mid transfer with no warning

Tags: rsync, freeze

Intermittently, I'll run into an issue where my rsync script will simply freeze mid transfer. This freeze may occur while downloading a file, or amidst listing uptodate files.

I'm running this on my mac, here's the code below:

```
rsync -vvhrtplHP -e "ssh" --rsync-path="sudo rsync" --filter=". $FILTER" --delete --delete-excluded --log-file="$BACKUP/log" --link-dest="$BACKUP/current/" $CONNECT:$BASE $BACKUP/$DATE/
```

For example, the console will output the download progress of a file, and stop at an arbitrary percentage and speed. The log doesn't even list the file (probably because it's incomplete).

I'll try numerous attempts and it'll freeze on different files or steps with no rhyme or reason. Terminal will show the loading icon while it's working, the output will freeze, and after a few seconds the loading icon vanishes.

Any ideas what could be causing this? I'm using rsync 3.1.0 on Mavericks. Could it be a connectivity issue or a system max execution time issue?

Comment: I'm on Mavericks too..... I guess we'll need to wait for an update.

Answer (score 0):

I have had rsync freezes in the past and I recall reading somewhere that it may have to do with rsync having to look for files to link, something increasingly difficult as you accumulate backup over backup. I suggest you skip the --link-dest in the next backup if your disk space allows it (to break the chain, so to speak).

As mentioned in https://serverfault.com/a/207693 you could use the hardlink command afterwards, I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Just had a similar problem while doing rsync from harddisk to a fat32 usb. rsync froze already in less than a second in my case and did not react at all after that.

Found out that the problem was a combination of usage of hardlinks on the harddisk and having fat32 filesystem on the usb drive, which does not support hardlinks.

[Formatting the usb drive with ext4](http://okomestudio.net/biboroku/?p=291) solved the problem for me.